# BS object has no attribute 'decompose'

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I'm doing the this tutorial ->
http://programminghistorian.org/lessons/intro-to-beautiful-soup

When I run the follow code I get this error:

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'decompose'

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup (open("43rd-congress.html"))

final_link = soup.p.a
final_link.decompose()

links = soup.find_all('a')

for link in links:
    print(link)
```

I can't understand why I'm getting this error. I'mm not sure what soup.p.a is doing either. Googled it but nothing came up...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that you have an html file named 43rd-congress.html within your working directory. And it must have the lines that are mentioned in the tutorial. The error you get, is most probably because the program was not able to find an "a" tag that is nested within an "p" tag in the file 43rd-congress.html that is within your working directory.

The soup.p.a lets you target and scrape out "a" tags that are nested within "p" tags and pass it to the assigned variable (final_link in this case). The decompose function will remove the elements stored in "final_link" from the original BeautifulSoup object "soup".

For example consider this example that is very similar to the one on the site you mentioned.

```
<p align="left">
    <a href="google.com">
    <b>Search Again</b>
    </a>
</p>
<a href="facebook.com">Hello</a>
<a href="mail.yahoo.com">Yahoo</a>
```

When you save the above code as 43rd-congress.html into your working directory and run your code you will see the output as

```
<a href="facebook.com">Hello</a>
<a href="mail.yahoo.com">Yahoo</a>
```

The "a" tag enclosed within the "p" tag is completely deleted from the "soup" object by action of the program.

Comment: Thanks!  It was the soup.p.a. which caused the problem. I didn't realise what it meant. Very clear now!